# Check if @PathVariable Data Binder result is null and throw 404

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In my spring boot app, i have a spring mvc method that secured with spring security 
I pass an id to this method as path variable and spring data argument resolver find and bind the entity
but when the id is invalid the entity is null ; i want throw a 404 when the entity is null; because spring security PreAuthorize require a not null entity to check user authorization;
my code is:

```
 @PutMapping(value = "/{address}")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and (#address.user.id == #user.id)")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseModel> update(@Valid @RequestBody AddressModel addressModel, @PathVariable Address address, @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {

        try {
            addressService.update(user, address, addressModel);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseModel(e.getMessage(), ResponseModel.ResponseStatus.ERROR), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseModel(messages.get("def.op.success"), ResponseModel.ResponseStatus.SUCCESS), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

also i tested

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and (#address != null and #address.user.id == #user.id)")
```

but it return a 403 error;

Comment: 403 represents no access so it is probably thrown by isAuthenticated() make sure you have right credentials to access this resource

Comment: @Mustahsan this is true; but i mentioned this part of code for hint; my problem with null addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you simply move the annotation to your service?

```
 @PutMapping(value = "/{address}")
    //@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and 
          //(#address.user.id == #user.id)") <-- move to service method
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseModel> update(
             @Valid @RequestBody AddressModel addressModel, @PathVariable Address address, 
                        @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {

        if(address == null){
           //throw some exception that gets translated to 404
        }

        try {
            //check will be applied on call to service
            addressService.update(user, address, addressModel);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseModel(e.getMessage(), 
                     ResponseModel.ResponseStatus.ERROR), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseModel(messages.get("def.op.success"), 
                 ResponseModel.ResponseStatus.SUCCESS), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```